# Would like to know how I can compare serial port data?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I just started learning to read and write data into serial port in c# using WPF. I would like to know how I can compare Data received from the serial port.
The data received from the serial port is displayed in a text box.

this is what I have tried.

```
do
{
    MainWindow.sp.WriteLine("M400");
    MainWindow.sp.WriteLine("M114");
    if (MainWindow.sp.ReadExisting() == "ok")
    {
        f2 = true;
        xml_flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        xml_flag = false;
    }
    
} while (xml_flag == false);
```

The problem that I face with the code is that the if condition does not get executed even though the data that I receive from the serial port is correct. It directly executes the else condition.

Hope someone could help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: If the if condition doesn't get executed, then the data returned by `ReadExisting()` is _not_ correct. Perhaps there are leading or trailing spaces you're not accounting for? What is the result of `BitConverter.ToString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MainWindow.sp.ReadExisting()));` when it's "correct"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. _**Please**_ format code in future questions!

Comment: I'd also recommend to not flood the Serial Port. As is, as long as `xml_flag` stays `false`, you are hammering it with messages as fast as possible.

Comment: This code will never work reliably with ReadExisting().  Which commonly will return "o", then "k" on the next call.  Except when you debug that code, now the artificial delay from stepping is long enough to get "ok".  You need to make it work with ReadLine(), configure the SerialPort.NewLine property as necessary to make it match the device behavior.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you so much. It works. You have given me a very good explanation to understand the basic functioning ReadExisting() and ReadLine():

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the RS232 device you get data from - the device can add (as commented above) space, CR or CRLF or LF, TAB - actually anything (or nothing) to signal "end of command".

I would dump the single bytes, formatted as HEX numbers to a text file/console, to verify data from the device.

Comment: @fym do I first convert the data from string to hex and then compare?

Comment: I would read the single bytrs from the serial port and convert them to hex gor display and verification. The compare should be done on byte level, when you know the bytes to find